# Converting Cosine Similarity Range from $[-1, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$

Tags: vectors, machine-learning

I'm working on computing the cosine similarity between two vectors in my project. While I understand that the standard cosine similarity ranges from $-1$ to $1$, I'm interested in transforming the similarity scores into a range of $[0, 1]$. I have two main approaches in mind, but I'm unsure about the best way to proceed.

1. Scaling Approach: simply scaling the cosine similarity values to the $[0, 1]$ range. Would this approach be valid and reliable? Are there any potential drawbacks or issues I should be aware of when applying this method?
2. Angular Similarity: which measures the angle between the vectors directly. Would using angular similarity inherently provide similarity scores in the $[0, 1]$ range, and is it a better alternative to the scaling approach?

Comment: Why not simply use the absolute value or square of the similarity? Also, if you could give us a better idea of what mapping the scores into the range $[0,1]$ is supposed to accomplish, we would have a better idea of what an appropriate way to do so would be

Comment: I intend to use the similarity score to filter my data. Any score greater than the threshold will be selected. So, I don't think that using the absolute value would be helpful, as a value of -1 would imply similarity, which is not true.

Comment: Why would that be any easier to do if you map it to the range [0,1]? In any case, a reasonable approach (potentially what you mean by "scaling") is to replace the rating $R$ with $\frac 12 (R + 1)$.